# Add extra information to Paypal checkout flow using Braintree Drop-inAndroid sdk

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, braintree

It is possible to show  list of items in the cart and total amount in the checkout page?
Im using braintree dropin i followed the documentation
This my code so far to build the dropin request, unlickely i don't see any required extra info

```
    val billingAddress = ThreeDSecurePostalAddress()
        .givenName("Antonio")
        .surname("Ianniello")
        .phoneNumber("341908570")
        .streetAddress("")
        .extendedAddress("")
        .locality("Italy")
        .region("IT")
        .postalCode("80038")
        .countryCodeAlpha2("EU")


    val additionalInformation = ThreeDSecureAdditionalInformation()
        .accountId("account-id")


    val threeDSecureRequest = ThreeDSecureRequest()
        .amount("100.00")
        .versionRequested(ThreeDSecureRequest.VERSION_2)
        .email("a.ianny@paypal.com")
        .mobilePhoneNumber("341908570")
        .billingAddress(billingAddress)
        .additionalInformation(additionalInformation)


    var paypalRequest = PayPalRequest()
        .displayName(PlaceDetailsActivity.selectedBeach.tenantName)
        .currencyCode("EUR")
        .lineItems(
            listOf<PayPalLineItem>(
                PayPalLineItem(
                    PayPalLineItem.KIND_DEBIT,
                    "Past",
                    "1",
                    "20"
                )
            )
        )


    val dropInRequest = DropInRequest()
        .paypalRequest(paypalRequest)
        .collectDeviceData(true)
        .requestThreeDSecureVerification(true)
        .threeDSecureRequest(threeDSecureRequest)
        .clientToken(clientToken)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Drop-In UI is a form for collecting payment information only, it does not collect checkout-specific fields.

To supply the additional information that is suggested for 3D Secure 2 with a Drop-In integration, you'll need to create your own form to collect this information from the user, and then [add that data to a ThreeDSecurerequest object](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/client-side#drop-in-ui).

For more information, contact [Braintree Support](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/help)